# Haskell list of lists multiplication

Tags: haskell

If I have 2 lists of lists in Haskell like the following:

```
[[1,1,1],[3,4,6],[1,2,3]] [[3,2,2],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]]
```

I must multiply the first lists, second lists, and so on.

The example above should result in

```
[[3,2,2],[9,16,30],[5,8,9]]
```

This is what I have done:

```
multListt xss yss = [zipWith (*) xs ys | xs <- xss, ys <- yss]
```

My result is:

```
[[3,2,2],[3,4,5],[5,4,3],[9,8,12],[9,16,30],[15,16,18],[3,4,6],[3,8,15],
[5,8,9]]
```

This means that my process takes 1 element of first list and multiplies it by all of the elements in list 2, and so on.

Can you please provide a clue to solve my issue?

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Answer (score 6):

Use `zipWith` twice.

```
multListt xss yss = zipWith (zipWith (*)) xss yss
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do using two nested calls to `zipWith` like this:

```
zipWith (zipWith (*)) [[1,1,1],[3,4,6],[1,2,3]] [[3,2,2],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]]
```

Or can use parallalel list comprehensions like that:

```
[zipWith (*) xs ys | xs <- [[1,1,1],[3,4,6],[1,2,3]] | ys <- [[3,2,2],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]]]
```

The last solution requires the `ParallelListComp` language extension.